# unable to delete javsacript object property

Tags: javascript

I created a object using `Object.create` in the following way.

```js
var myObject = {
  price: 20.99,
  get_price: function() {
    return this.price;
  }
};

var customObject = Object.create(myObject, {
    price: {
      value: 100
    }
  }
);

console.log(delete customObject.price);
```

I tried to delete customObject  price using

`delete customObject.price` returns `false`

Comment: Try dropping a `console.log(customObject)` after deleting `customObject.price`. It works for me.

Comment: Well, you've created a [non-configurable property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Properties). Make sure to always use strict mode to get [a meaningful error message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_delete).

Comment: @Zenoo `console.log` has nothing to do with this

Comment: @Bergi I didn't say `console.log()` had anything to do with it. I'm just showing OP that what he tried actually works.

Comment: @Zenoo What do you mean by "it actually works"? Surely the `.price` property still exists.

Comment: @Bergi No it doesn't. I tested it in Chrome 65, and the property got deleted even if the delete returned false.

Comment: @Zenoo I cannot reproduce. I'm on Chrome 65.0.3325.181 (Windows, 64-Bit) and the `customObject.price` stays 100.

Comment: @Bergi I managed to narrow the issue down : The property stays in the actual object properties, but a StackOverflow snippet won't show it in its console.

Comment: @Zenoo Sure, it's not enumerable as well as not configurable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter to `Object.create()` is interpreted exactly the same way as the second parameter of `Object.defineProperties()`.  That `false` is being returned from the `delete` expression because the property you're deleting is an own non-configurable property and you're not in "strict" mode. In "strict" mode you'd get an exception.

If you created the property with the "configurable" flag set to `true`, you would get `true` from the `delete`:

```
var customObject = Object.create(myObject, {
    price: {
      value: 100,
      configurable: true
    }
  }
);
```

Or you can create the object and just set the property with a simple assignment:

```
var customObject = Object.create(myObject);
customObject.price = 100;
```

Such properties are always "born" as configurable.

You can use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(customObject, "price")` to check whether the property you're deleting is configurable:

```
if (Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(customObject, "price").configurable)
  delete customObject.price;
```

Comment: Thanks @Pointy  please add this function too to check if the property is configurable or not `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor( obj, prop )` in the answer.